# Remove files older than x days in a loop without using find unix

Tags: bash, unix, aix

I am attempting to delete file older than x days in a loop without having to find them.
I am using this script to delete all of them:

```
for f in /path/tomy/directory/*.rpt
do
   # if file, delete it
   [ -f "$f" ] && rm "$f"
done
```

How do I incorporate Mtime in this

Comment: Why "without `find`"? It's pretty much the standard tool this use case.

Comment: [`man stat`](http://www.polarhome.com/service/man/?qf=stat&tf=2&of=AIX&sf=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a temporary file with a timestamp of X days ago and then inside your `for` loop compare each file's timestamp with that file to decide whether to delete it or not.

```
n=60 # number of days
ref="/tmp/$$.tmp" # temporary filename

touch -t $(date -d "-$n days" '+%Y%m%d%H%M.%S') "$ref"

for f in /path/tomy/directory/*.rpt; do
   [[ -f $f && $ref -nt $f ]] && echo rm "$f"
done

rm "$ref"
```

Once you're satisfied with the output, remove `echo` before `rm`.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently I cannot use `-d` on AIX is there an alternative?

Comment: Replace `$(date -d "-$n days" '+%Y%m%d%H%M.%S')` with `201712040000.00` for date that is the date 10 days back.